# jQuery custom event not firing or triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in the given below code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#sp7').on("test", processData);

function processData(e){
recievedData=null;
recievedData[e.message[id]] = e.message;
return recievedData;
}

function testData(id,a){
temp = {id:id, a:a};
$.event.trigger({
type : "test",
message : temp,
time : new Date()
});
}

</script>
```

I am calling the `testData` on a button click:

```
<input type = "button" onclick="testData(1,'a1');" value="test1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you specifically need to resort to custom events. However, the event should be triggered on the dom element that is supposed to listen to it. Like

```
$('#sp7').trigger('test',[parameters]);
```